# How do I detect which direction a UIImageview is animating?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What is the best way to detect the direction of a uiimageview?

I want to detect when a uiimageview is 'falling' - this is because it follows an arc animation for jumping purposes, i only want to detect when it is 'falling' and intersecting a floor, rather than when it jumps and intersects the floor.

I'm guessing there is no built in method to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how is the animation/transformation defined?

Comment: By adding a CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath to the uiimageview's layer

Comment: is it not possible to find out from by querying the frame or by timing calcualtion?

Comment: It's ok, I figured I can just test my path for interesction with a floor, then redraw the path so the end point is on the floor not below it

Comment: @Adam Carter -- please create an answer with your solution and accept your answer. Otherwise it looks like this question is still open!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do, I found, was to draw a path and test it for collision with any above 'floors' or platforms. Then if it does collide, draw another path with an end point matching the y position of the collided platform.